# blackberry supports j2me polish classes?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, j2mepolish

Do blackberry supports j2me polish classes because when i use it with blackberry api;s in my application it shows me following error of the in built classes of the j2me polish

```
C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\j2mepolish-src\j2me\src\de\enough\polish\midp\ui\Form.java:42: interface expected here
    [javac] implements Displayable
    [javac] ^
    [javac] C:\Program Files\J2ME-Polish\j2mepolish-src\j2me\src\de\enough\polish\midp\ui\TextBox.java:42: interface expected here
    [javac] implements Displayable
    [javac] ^
```

Comment: How do you build app? Did you put RIM jar in classpath?

Comment: i have added classpath in build.xml "classpath="${polish.home}/lib/enough-j2mepolish-build.jar:${polish.home}/lib/jdom.jar:${polish.home}/import/BlackBerry-5.0.0.jar:C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 4.1.0\lib\net_rim_api.jar"

Comment: After adding the above jar file i am getting the same error

Comment: Check your classpath, because I see column there instead of semicolumn.

Comment: replaced ":" by ";" but still getting same error

Comment: You certainly should be able to do this.  [Here's one tutorial online](http://smhumayun.blogspot.com/2007/11/j2me-development-with-netbeans.html)